# Spectral theorems for generalized Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, hilbert-spaces, eigenvector

Let $k$ be a field, and let $\sigma$ be a nontrivial involutory automorphism of $k$. Let $A$ be a square matrix with entries in $k$, such that $(A^{\sigma})^T = A$; here $A^\sigma$ means the matrix $(a_{ij}^\sigma)$, where $A = (a_{ij})$, and the $T$-exponent means "transposed of."

*Example*: $k = \mathbb{C}$ and $\sigma$ is complex conjugation. In that case, $A$ is called a *Hermitian matrix*.

*Question*: Is there a spectral theorem known which naturally generalizes the spectral theorem for complex Hermitian matrices?

What about if $k$ is algebraically closed, or real-closed?